# GWT: UiBinder and MVP

Tags: gwt, mvp, uibinder

I am rather new to GWT and been trying to follow Activities and Places tutorial. Everything has worked very well until I had to use SuggestBox. In a SuggestBox you pass the Oracle in the constructor and there is not setOracle method.
If I understood correctly, the idea in activities and places tutorial is to have the views just instantiated once since are expensive objects but then that poses a problem. If I want to keep the oracle in the presenter and I create the view BEFORE the presenter, how do I get to work all together? @UiField(provided=true) and instantiate the suggestbox from the presenter wont do since SuggestBox cannot be null when I init the widget...
With CellTable is fairly easy since there is a setModel method but with SuggestBox or CellBrowser I have no idea in how to proceed. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually almost no reason to *set* the `SuggestOracle` from the presenter.

But if you want it, you can easily make a `SuggestOracle` that calls back to the presenter, or a `SuggestOracle` that simply wraps another oracle, one that you could swap at runtime, and thus set from the presenter.

Comment: Well. I use clientfactory in the presenter and all the services are instantiated there. If I create the suggestOracle (which is asynchronous) in the view, then I cannot pass the service reference from the presenter and it gets kind of messy. The delegate pattern I guess would do although feel kinds of patchy. I wonder if the wrap method in suggestoracle is meant for this? But then again, with cellbrowser happens the same and there is no wrap method there..